# How to fix apt-get: command not found in Ubuntu 18.10?

Tags: apt, paths, anaconda

I'm trying to install software in Ubuntu 18.10 with `sudo apt-get` command, but it gave me the error – `apt-get: command not found`. I used `locate apt-get` and found that apt-get is located in `/usr/bin`, which is in the `$PATH`. It still gave me the error. What should I do?

```
$ sudo apt-get
sudo: apt-get: command not found
$ locate apt-get
/snap/core/5662/usr/local/bin/apt-get
/snap/core/5662/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/apt-get
/snap/core/5662/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/slapt-get
/snap/core/5897/usr/local/bin/apt-get
/snap/core/5897/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/apt-get
/snap/core/5897/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/slapt-get
/snap/core/6130/usr/local/bin/apt-get
/snap/core/6130/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/apt-get
/snap/core/6130/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/slapt-get
/usr/local/bin/apt-get
/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/apt-get
/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/slapt-get
/usr/share/man/de/man8/apt-get.8.gz
/usr/share/man/fr/man8/apt-get.8.gz
/usr/share/man/it/man8/apt-get.8.gz
/usr/share/man/ja/man8/apt-get.8.gz
/usr/share/man/man8/apt-get.8.gz
/usr/share/man/nl/man8/apt-get.8.gz
$ echo $PATH
/home/guan/anaconda3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin
:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

Comment: It's really weird that you have your "snapshot" folder in your PATH? Did you manually add it? - I'd remove that might cause really weird things like what you're experiencing. If nothing have you tried running apt-get calling with the full path? `/usr/bin/apt-get`

Comment: I didn't add anything manually into PATH. I tried to use full path of apt, it didn't work either.

Comment: Output of `ls -l /usr/bin/apt-get` ?

Comment: Here is the result of `ls -l /usr/bin/apt-get`     `-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 134968 12月 8 2016 /usr/bin/apt-get`

Comment: By default, `sudo` on Ubuntu doesn't use `PATH`, it uses its own `secure_path`: what is the output of `sudo /bin/grep -r secure_path /etc/sudoers{,.d}` ?

Comment: `/etc/sudoers:Defaults secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin"
`